# Return current User in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Using PHP and Laravel 4 I have a method in my User model like this below to check for Admin user...

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    if(isset($this->user_role)  && $this->user_role === 'admin'){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work when I call this function in other classes  or models though.

To get the desired result I had to do it like this instead...

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    if(isset(Auth::user()->user_role)  && Auth::user()->user_role === 'admin'){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am trying to access this inside my Admin Controller like this below but it returns an empty User object instead of current logged in user Object...

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

So my question is how can I get the first version to work?  When I instantiate a User object in another class, I need to somehow make sure it has the data for the current logged in user but I am not sure the best way to do that...I know this is basic I am just a little rusty right now could use the help, thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This returns the user repository - not the current logged in user

```
public function __construct(User $user)
```

To access the current logged in user ANYWHERE in your application - just do

```
Auth::user()
```

(like your middle example)

So therefore - to check if a user is an admin user ANYWHERE in your application - just do

```
if (Auth::user()->isAdmin())
{
     // yes
}
else
{
     // no
}
```

Comment: Laravel is very cool but it almost seems it does too much work that it's hard to know what's going on.  I guess I just need to learn the framework more I am use to doing stuff from scratch...kind of funny that using the framework would be harder for me

Comment: @jasondavis Keep at it, reference the docs, after using it for a year or so, it's amazing and I'd never go back.

Comment: @DustinGraham In the 10 months since I made that comment, I also could not see going back now, it is simply amazing.  MY only complaint is I wish there was also a lightweight version for small micro projects.  Laravel v3 used to have a single file lite version and it would be super cool if that was possible with L4 but I doubt it is now.

Comment: @HardyMathew - yes - it should

Comment: @JasonDavis Your wish has been granted. You now have Lumen!

Comment: @Jumper I was wondering what you meant but now I see... http://lumen.laravel.com/ this is super amazing, makes my day!  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: how to access current user in js?